# Excel VBA that will copy real time data from a column into the next column, by time intervals across the sheet

Tags: excel, vba, real-time

I am having trouble creating some vba for a project that involves real time intervals.
The sheet originally created and used for this some 8 years a ago has disappeared in a Windows update last year.  For the life of me I can not recreate the code after all this time.

I want to have have the data in column A move to the next column ater a specific time interval.  Column A has real time data that changes in milliseconds and I want to record data from that column at a set time interval eg 1 minute.

At the next 1 minute mark, the new data in column A is to be moved into column B and the previous saved data in Column B is now pasted into Column C.  At the next 1 minute mark the data in Column A goes to B, B goes to C and C goes to D etc.

Attached is a mockup of how it would look in the sheet, with original data feed in Column A and the captured data from the feed every 1 minute moving across the sheet -
[Data Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoQHo.jpg)

What I did find was a snippet of code I started with that may explain what I was trying to achieve.  The friend that helped me with this in 2012 is no longer alive but he started with this -

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Columns.Count <> 16 Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Range("b5:b30").Value = Range("b5:b30").Value
    Range("b5:b30").Value = Range("a5:a30").Value
```

I tried to copy/paste and change the `Range' lines in the VBA page for each column but it didn't work.  I am actually hoping that there may be a simpler way to do this rather than writing the range lines for each column of the sheet.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. Please, upload an input sample and your expected output. How is the data saved there? Is time required?

Comment: thanks Tim for fixing up the code placement.  David I am not sure I understand what you are asking, I am an amateur cell formula person.  So I'll do an edit

Comment: Please, show us the data (one screenshot capture) so we can imagine how your data looks like. After it, I will give that code for you and we will see. What I was asking is how this file will work with the data you are introducing. Please, just upload a screenshot of the input data. (Expected output is clear for me)

Comment: Thanks David, the input data is just one column (A) of numbers, from row 5 down to any number of rows to a maximum of row 30.  The number of rows with data will vary each time the sheet/workbook is opened.  A mockup has been edited into the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Dim i As Long

Sub test()
If i = 0 Then
    i = 1
Else
    i = i + 1
End If

Range("A5:A34").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("B3").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("B3").Value = "Minute " & i
Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "test"

End Sub

Sub Reset()
    i=0
End Sub
```

First line is to declare one counter that will work each time that you use the code. One Procedure call `test` that will shift the values one the first column to the second one, as well as it will introduce the header. After one minute, it will shift 1st and 2nd columns and so on. There is another procedure to reset the counter.

In order to make it easy for your, just create 2 buttons on top of the header like "Run" and "Reset" and call this macros from there.

If you have any issue, just let me know.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks David, this did take the data from column A and placed it in Column B as expected but deletes the formulas in Col A that retrieve the data.  And there it stopped.  The data would not transfer to column C.  On the  2nd and 3rd attempts at this, Excel crashed.  Not sure what is happening here yet.